Help me understand the answer given to this old question (1747)
The following problem is very easy to solve, especially with modern mathematics. What I don’t understand, is the solution given back in 1748, by the mathematician J. Turner. His solution has some historical significance, as an early application of partial differentiation.
The historian of mathematics, Florian Cajori, writes 1: “The pre-Eulerian history of the partial processes of the calculus is difficult to trace, for the reason that there existed at that time no recognized symbolism nor technical phraseology which would distinguish the partial processes from the ordinary ones”. This is one of the cases he examines in his article:

$$\text{Questions proposed in 1747 and answered in 1748}$$
$$\text{I. Question 279, by Mr Landen}$$

                  A charming brisk maid has assur’d me and said,
                       Since I’m such a fine mathematician 
                 (Laying puzzling aside, for the joys of a bride)
                     She will wed me – but on this condition: 
                  That I first shall unfold what* pieces of gold
                         Her father has for her in store:
                   And these I must find from the data subjoin’d,
                          And then I’m to puzzle no more.
                  


*The pieces are half guineas, guineas, moidores and three pound twelves.
The whole number is 4000. And if $u$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ be put for the number of each sort respectively, $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z$ is a maximum. Quere what is the lady's fortune?  2

My solution:
Let $f(u,x,y,z)=u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z$, while $u+x+y+z=4000=b.$
The variables $u$, $x$, $y$ and $z$, take such values, as to make $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z$ maximum. Thus, we shall treat $f$ as a composite function, since $u+x+y+z=b$ and without this restriction, it wouldn't have a maximum.
Solving for $z$, we get: $z=b-u-x-y$ and then, by substituting $z$
in the initial equation:
$$f(u,x,y,z)=u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}(b-u-x-y)$$
$$=u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}b-u^{5}x^{3}y^{2}-u^{4}x^{4}y^{2}-u^{4}x^{3}y^{3}$$
At the maximum, all partial derivatives should be zero. Thus, we get:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}=u^{3}x^{3}y^{2}\left(4b-5u-4x-4y\right)=0$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=u^{4}x^{2}y^{2}\left(3b-3u-4x-3y\right)=0$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=u^{4}x^{3}y\left(2b-2u-2x-3y\right)=0$$
Eliminating the factors in the left of each one, and since $b$ is
known, we end up with a system of 3 linear equations with 3 unknowns,
with the solution $u=\frac{4}{10}b=1600$, $x=\frac{3}{10}b=1200$
and $y=\frac{1}{5}b=800$.
Then, $z=b-u-x-y=400$.
J. Turner arrives at the same results:

$$\text{Answered by Mr. J. Turner}$$
Let $u$ = the half guineas, $x$ = guineas, $y$ = moidores and $z$
= 3l 12s. By the question, $u+x+y+z=4000=b$:
Now $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z$ being a maximum, or (expunging $z$) $b-u-x-y=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$.
In fluxions, $-\dot{u}-\dot{x}-\dot{y}=\dfrac{-2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}-\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}-\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$;
whence $\dot{y}=\dfrac{2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}$; $\dot{x}=\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$;
$\dot{u}=\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$. And $\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}=\dfrac{y}{2}=\dfrac{x}{3}=\dfrac{u}{4}=b-u-x-y$.
Consequently, $x=\frac{3}{2}y$; $u=\frac{4}{3}x=2y$: Also $\frac{1}{2}y=b-2y-\frac{3}{2}y-y$;
or $y=\frac{1}{5}b$; $z=\frac{1}{10}b$; $x=\frac{3}{10}b$; $u=\frac{4}{10}b$;
and the lady's fortune is 46201. Hence this.

Questions:
How $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z$ being a maximum, gives $b-u-x-y=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$?
Why is it even valid?
By restoring $z$, we get: $z=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}\Rightarrow u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z=1$. But this is obviously false, since $u$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all positive integers greater than 1.
Do I miss something? And if I don't and it is indeed false, then how does he arrives at the correct answer in the end?

Note: "Fluxions" are time derivatives, so there is no direct
representation of a partial derivative in Newtonian symbolism and
one has to work in an indirect way: $$-\dot{u}-\dot{x}-\dot{y}=\dfrac{-2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}-\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}-\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$$
is actually a total derivative, which uses a partial differentiation methodology. In modern notation: $$b-u-x-y=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}\Rightarrow\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(b-u-x-y\right)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$$
$$-\dfrac{du}{dt}-\dfrac{dx}{dt}-\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u}\dfrac{du}{dt}+\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$$
where $h=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$ and thus $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial u}=-\dfrac{4}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$,
$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}=-\dfrac{3}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$ and
$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{2}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}$.
Newton himself follows a similar approach at least in one occasion, in his “Method of fluxions” 3.

References:

Florian Cajori, “The Early History of Partial Differential Equations and of Partial Differentiation and Integration”, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 35, No. 9 (Nov., 1928), pp. 459-467. You can find it here.

“The Mathematical Questions proposed in the Lady's Diary”, by Thomas Leybourn, vol.1, London (1817), p.395. You can find it here.

“The Method of Fluxions and Infinite Series: With Its Application to the Geometry of Curve-lines”. By Sir Isaac Newton, (English translation by John Colson 1736, original in Latin, 1671), p. 21. You can find it here.



Only a detail: this kind of "fluxions" notation with a dot is still in use today, at least it was when I was a student. While $V$ is a volume $\dot{V}$ is a flow rate.

@m-stgt Yes, the dot notation is still in use, especially in physics, to denote time derivatives. The point here is that, the fluxions are only time derivatives, so, if one needs to represent derivatives of other variables using Newton's notation, he has to do so in an indirect manner.

It is true that Newton / Turner / ETC were all using time even when time was irrelevant. Thus Turner gets the right answer almost co-incidentally , @ArisMakrides , because the mistakes cancel out.

It seems that there are 2 "mistakes" (at least according to modern ways with modern thinking using modern notation) here , which somehow "cancel" each other , to give the correct answer !
Original Way :
Correct : $u+x+y+z=4000=b$
Correct : $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z=maximum$
Mistake : $b-u-x-y=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$ : It should be $b-u-x-y=\dfrac{maximum}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$ : Still , let us accept the mistake here.
Correct : In fluxions, $-\dot{u}-\dot{x}-\dot{y}=\dfrac{-2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}-\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}-\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$ (though it is not explicitly saying which is the independent variable : It is implicitly taking either $z$ or $t$ or something unknown)
At that time , it was common to take time variable [ even when $t$ was not generally involved ] to get $\dot{y} = (dy/dt)$ , $\dot{y}/\dot{x} = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt) \equiv (dy/dx)$ ...
It is not clear whether Turner had moved forward to $\dot{y} = (\partial y/\partial z)$
Mistake : Converting that Single Equation to the System [[ $\dot{y}=\dfrac{2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}$; $\dot{x}=\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$; $\dot{u}=\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$ ]] is generally not valid.
It is like $A+Bi=C+Di$ giving $A=B$ with $C=D$.
It is more like $A_1+A_2\sqrt{2}+A_3\sqrt{3}+A_4\sqrt{5}=B_1+B_2\sqrt{2}+B_3\sqrt{3}+B_4\sqrt{5}$ giving $A_i=B_i$ with Integers.
It will not work here.
While we generally can not do that , yet , it is that mistake which is going to rectify the earlier mistake.
Correct : Converting $\dot{x}=\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$ to $1=\dfrac{3}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$ , $\dfrac{x}{3}=\dfrac{1}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{4}}$
Correct : Making all the LHS terms Equal the Common RHS , to get the ratios right.
Correct : Getting the Overall Solution right.
Corrected Way :
With modern thinking , we can write it like this :
$u+x+y+z=4000=b$
$z=b-u-x-y$
Let $x$ vary with $z$ while the other variables are constant : Partial Derivative will give :
$\partial z / \partial x = -1$
$u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z=maximum$
$z=\dfrac{maximum}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$
Let $x$ vary with $z$ while the other variables are constant : Partial Derivative will give :
$\partial z / \partial x = -\dfrac{3 \times maximum}{u^{4}x^{4}y^{2}}$
Thus , $-1 = -\dfrac{3 \times maximum}{u^{4}x^{4}y^{2}}$
Multiplying my $-x/3$ , we get :
$\dfrac{x}{3} = \dfrac{maximum}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$
Likewise we get :
$\dfrac{y}{2} = \dfrac{maximum}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$
$\dfrac{u}{4} = \dfrac{maximum}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$
Common RHS will make the LHS terms give the ratios : $\dfrac{y}{2}=\dfrac{x}{3}=\dfrac{u}{4}$
Overall Solution is then available.
Turner has ignored the $maximum$ Numerator , though that eventually (co-incidentally) cancels , making it work out.
Turner has made that a "general rule" :


We need 4 linear equations to make the 4 variables of $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z$ dependent on each other, but we only have one. By eliminate $z$, $b-u-x-y=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$ has 3 independent variables. Time is irrelevant with our case, thus $\dot{u}$, $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ can also vary independently of each other. So, we can assume that the two of them are zero while the third is not, and get $\dot{y}=\dfrac{2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3} u^{4}}$; $\dot{x}=\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$; $\dot{u}=\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$.
So, that step is valid. Please share your thoughts.

Although I agree that it is unlikely that Turner used something similar
to the method of Lagrange multipliers, I think @BobDobbs has a point,
at least for the reason why the final answer is correct: the numerator
of $\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$ is not important.

Let $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z=m$, then $z=\dfrac{m}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$. Now, $$-\dot{u}-\dot{x}-\dot{y}=\dfrac{-2\dot{y}m}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}-\dfrac{3\dot{x}m}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}-\dfrac{4\dot{u}m}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$$ is correct, and $\dot{y}=\dfrac{2\dot{y}m}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}$; $\dot{x}=\dfrac{3\dot{x}m}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$;
$\dot{u}=\dfrac{4\dot{u}m}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$ is also correct. Hence,
$\dfrac{m}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}=\dfrac{y}{2}=\dfrac{x}{3}=\dfrac{u}{4}=b-u-x-y$.
This gives the same result as the answer.

(1) I am not saying time is involved , I am saying what Newton , Turner , ETC thought at that time, Check [[ https://www.britannica.com/science/fluxion ]] [[ https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7083/was-newtons-method-of-finding-derivatives-of-his-fluents-based-on-applying-the ]] where we can see that time was always involved. Implicitly , $\dot{y}$ was $dy/dt$ , while $\dot{y}/\dot{x}$ was $(dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$ to give our modern $dy/dx$ , even when time was irrelevant. Our modern treatment is not like that.

(2) We know Numerator is not important here , though Turner thought it was important to generate a Conclusion. , when it was actually not important. When we have Cases where Numerator is indeed important , Turner may not accidentally get the right answer.

(3) That is what I highlight in my answer. In modern terms , when we have $\partial z / \partial x +\partial z / \partial y = x^2+y^3$ , we can not make it $\partial z / \partial x = x^2$ with $\partial z / \partial y = y^3$, It is even more harder when we have $\partial z / \partial x +\partial z / \partial y = x^2+y^3+8$ : Should we get $\partial z / \partial x = x^2+4$ with $\partial z / \partial y = y^3+4$ ? We can not take the Single Equation to make the System here !

I think J. Turner was ahead of his time. He knew that maximum is not so important but ratio of variables are. The simalar philosophy happens in the method of Lagrange multipliers which I recommend for a quick solution. According to this theory, the gradient vectors of the optimization function and constraint function must be parallel at the optimal point. Hence,
$$\vec\nabla(u^4x^3y^2z)=\lambda\vec\nabla(u+x+y+z-b)$$
which immediately gives
$$\frac4u=\frac3x=\frac2y=\frac1z=\frac{\lambda}{u^4x^3y^2z}$$
and the solution.

The method you suggest might work out , though it is unlikely that Turner used something like that. Turner not only gives importance to maxima ("the term being a maximum") , Turner gives a wrong conclusion when eliminating $z$ , losing the chance to use a ratio. Moreover , that Equation will not convert to that System , introducing suspicion over the method. It is more likely that certain heuristics were used without using Partial Derivatives , while ignoring the mistakes.

After further thought and research, I came to the conclusion that John Turner just made a mistake. He was not ahead of his time and he was not following some special heuristic which could justify it. I can not rule out the possibility that Turner was aware about it and he did not care, knowing that it would not affect the final results. But even if so, it is a mistake never the less. I will explain why, but first, let me explain why there is only one mistake in Turner's answer.
When I first encounter the problem, I had the same thought as @Prem : Going from (1) $$-\dot{u}-\dot{x}-\dot{y}=\dfrac{-2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}-\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}-\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$$
to $\dot{y}=\dfrac{2\dot{y}}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}$; $\dot{x}=\dfrac{3\dot{x}}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$;
$\dot{u}=\dfrac{4\dot{u}}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$; (2)
is not correct.
So, there are two mistakes. Then, they may be, somehow, cancel each
other.
But after contemplating a bit more, I rejected that thought.
Indeed, that step wouldn't be correct, if $z=\dfrac{1}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$ (3) was a composite function, with variables depending on time. But it is not such a function. In fact, $u$, $x$ and $y$ are independent from each other: at least, if one ignores the fact that their values should only be natural numbers, in which case we wouldn't have a continue function and we wouldn't be able to apply differentiation, and also they would not be allowed to take negative values, and this puts an additional upper boundary on their values, that is, no variable can have a value greater than 4000. So, we should ignore these details, in order to use differentiation with no further assumptions, and Turner does so.
In this context, the three variables can vary independently and freely. Now, since time is irrelevant to the problem, the fluxions $\dot{u}$, $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ can also vary independently of each other. The fact that they are all time derivatives shouldn't be of any significance, since they are not even obligated to refer to the same time interval. But I shouldn't take credit for this thought: Florian Cajori warns against this assumption in his article. While he agree with some writers that, in the published works of Newton (and also Leibniz), there are no partial differential equations to be found, he disagree with the reason why. For these writers, the problem is that, in Newton's work, all variables are dependent upon a single free variable, which is time. I quote the reasoning of one of them and then the response from Cajori:
Hoppe of Göttingen writes (Ref1):

When Newton has an equation in several fluents (we would say in
variable magnitudes), that is, in $x$, $y$, $z$, $u$ etc., he
derives the fluxions by assuming that this variables are all functions
of one and the same variable magnitude, for example, of the time.
Then he remarks the fluxion of $x$ by $\dot{x}$, of $y$ by $\dot{y}$,
etc., so that $\dot{x}$means in our notation $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, $\dot{y}=\dfrac{dy}{dt}$,
$\dot{z}=\dfrac{dz}{dt}$ . Accordingly, if Newton had chosen to write
his fluent equation briefly $f(x,y,z...)=u$, he would have meant
by this, that $x$, $y$, $z$,...,$u$ are functions of $t$, but
not ... that $u$ is a function of the independent variables $x$,
$y$, $z$,... . [...] If Newton wanted to represent $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$
he had to write $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dt}\div\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dot{y}\div\dot{x}=\alpha:1$,
where $\alpha$ is a magnitude measured according to the unit of the
fluxions... In this theory of fluxions no path was open for partial
differential equations

And then Cajori comments (Ref2):

These writers are correct in stating that all fuxions are time-derivatives, but where in Newton and other writers on fluxions is it stated that all fluxions must result from contemporaneous fluents? Why is it not possible to consider the velocity (fluxion) of $u$, when only $x$changes, or when only $y$ or $z$ changes? These continental writers assume all fluxions to be contemporaneous and do not go to the trouble to see what practice of British writers really was in this respect. To
show the error of this contention it is sufficient to quote from Newton
and other writers on fluxions where partial processes freely enter.

The answer to the puzzle by Turner, is exactly one of those examples Cajori provides, just after quoting Newton himself. Thus, in practice, the British writers of that time, would use the fluxions of independent variables, without the assumption that they where all functions of the same single independent variable. @Prem is right, however: we wouldn't do something like that with modern mathematics, because we don't need to. We have better tools.
How would we do it? Firstly, if our variables were not dependent upon time, we wouldn't use time derivatives at all, and time would not occurred at all in our calculation. You can not do that, however, if all your variables are representing fluents. In the case we did want to represent rates of change in respect of different time intervals, we would use different time variables for each one, like $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$. In this case, it is obvious that $\dfrac{dx}{dt_{1}}$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dt_{2}}$ can vary independently of each other and there is no suggestion that $x$ and $y$ are dependent upon the same variable. But how can you do that using the dot notation, where the variable of time is nowhere to be found? So, the pair of $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ can either have the interpretation $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, or the interpretation $\dfrac{dx}{dt_{1}}$
and $\dfrac{dy}{dt_{2}}$, and the right interpretation will be given
by the context of the problem, not by the mathematical notation.
But if we can assume that $\dot{u}$, $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ vary independently of each other, then we can further assume that the two of them are zero while the third is not. Applying that to (1), we get the results in (2). So, that step is correct and then, there is only one mistake in Turner's solution, that is, the numerator of the left expression in (3).
Since there is only one mistake, there is no other possible reason
for why the final answer is correct, than that the mistake is irrelevant. This became clear to me, especially after @BobDobbs answer. Then, I notice that, by starting with $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z=m$, and thus $z=\dfrac{m}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}$, we can follow exactly the same steps as Turner, with the only difference that we introduce the factor $m$ in some terms: $$b-u-x-y=\dfrac{m}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}\Rightarrow$$
$$-\dot{u}-\dot{x}-\dot{y}=\dfrac{-2\dot{y}m}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}-\dfrac{3\dot{x}m}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}-\dfrac{4\dot{u}m}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$$
whence $\dot{y}=\dfrac{2\dot{y}m}{y^{3}x^{3}u^{4}}$; $\dot{x}=\dfrac{3\dot{x}m}{y^{2}x^{4}u^{4}}$;
$\dot{u}=\dfrac{4\dot{u}m}{y^{2}x^{3}u^{5}}$ and $\dfrac{m}{u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}}=\dfrac{y}{2}=\dfrac{x}{3}=\dfrac{u}{4}=b-u-x-y$.
Consequently, $x=\frac{3}{2}y$; $u=\frac{4}{3}x=2y$: Also $\frac{1}{2}y=b-2y-\frac{3}{2}y-y$;
or $y=\frac{1}{5}b$; $z=\frac{1}{10}b$; $x=\frac{3}{10}b$; $u=\frac{4}{10}b$;
The first, but I think strong evidence, that the problem with the numerator in Turner's answer is just a mistake, is that no more work is needed to derive the same results in the correct way. So, no special method is needed. But then, an even stronger evidence occurred.
There is a reference in Cajorie's article that I hadn't follow: In
page 464, after presenting Turner's solution, Cajori comments that
"Practically the same problem is solved in the same way by William
Emerson" (Ref3). I probably omitted this for two reasons: Firstly,
why to bother, if it is the same thing. Secondly, at the time, I was
looking for examples that where preceding Euler (1748), and Emerson's
publication was a later one (1768). When I finally followed that reference, I found that Emerson solved the problem almost in the same way as Turner: the difference is that the numerator in (3) is $m$!
So, Emerson begins with $u^{4}x^{3}y^{2}z=m$, (actually, $xy^{2}u^{3}z^{4}=m$) and follows the same steps as above.
At that time, I conjectured that Emerson found and corrected Turners answer. But then it occurred to me, that the reference in Cajorie's article, was about the third, revised edition of Emerson's book. When was the first edition published? Does it also contain the same problem?
Thanks to the “Internet Archive”, it was easy to find the first edition, which was publish in 1743 (Ref4). I started to flip through the book, and, voilà! On page 128, the same problem and solution is found.
The problem in Emerson's book, does not contains the little poem in
the beginning, and it does not talk about gold coins. It just states:
"To find $xy^{2}u^{3}z^{4}$ a maximum so that $x+y+u+z=b$".
Notice that the variables share the same exponents with our version,
but in different order. The solutions of Emerson and Turner are remarkably similar, especially when the proper adjustments are made: $x$ (Emerson) should take the place of $z$ (Turner), $u$ (E) the place of $x$ (T) and $z$ (E) the place of $u$ (T). Then, even the details are
the same.
Turner concludes:

Consequently, $x=\frac{3}{2}y$; $u=\frac{4}{3}x=2y$: Also $\frac{1}{2}y=b-2y-\frac{3}{2}y-y$;
or $y=\frac{1}{5}b$; $z=\frac{1}{10}b$; $x=\frac{3}{10}b$; $u=\frac{4}{10}b$;

Emerson concludes:

Therefore $u=\frac{3}{2}y$, $z=\frac{4}{3}u=2y$, and therefore $\frac{1}{2}y=b-2y-\frac{3}{2}y-y$,
or $y=\frac{1}{5}b$; hence $x=\frac{1}{10}b$, $y=\frac{2}{10}b$,
$u=\frac{3}{10}b$, $z=\frac{4}{10}b$.

After the substitutions, even the order of the calculation is the same and this can not be a coincidence: Turner copied Emerson's solution, unless they both copied it from a third source. In any case, if my math is correct, 1743 precedes 1748 and thus, Cajori should have presented Emerson's solution, as an early example of partial differentiation, instead of Turner's. I believe he would, if he had access to the first edition of Emerson's book. Then, I wouldn't got my self in all this trouble. Unfortunately, Cajori (1859-1930) didn't have Internet Archive.
By taking all of this into account, I believe the most probable answer to why Turner has 1 as the numerator is because he made a mistake, and the reason why he nevertheless arrives in the correct solution, it is because the numerator is irrelevant to the solution, as I have shown above.
Finally, here are two extracts, one from Emerson's book (1743) and one from the "The Mathematical Questions proposed in the Lady's Diary" (1817), which saves the question asked in 1747 by Landen, and answered in 1948 by Turner, from the "Lady's Diary" almanac of those years. From the later, I extract only the answer, so you can compare the two of them yourselves.
The answer in Emerson's book:



References

Unfortunatly Cajori does not provide any further reference.

The quote from Cajory, is from the same article that is referenced in my Question above. See page 463.

William Emerson, “The doctrine of fluxions: not only explaining the elements thereof, but also its application and use in the several parts of mathematics and natural philosophy”. 3d ed., cor. and greatly enlarged, London, Printed for Robinson and Roberts, 1768, pp. 174-175. Find it here.

William Emerson, “The doctrine of fluxions: not only explaining the elements thereof, but also its application and use in the several parts of mathematics and natural philosophy”. London : printed by J. Bettenham and sold by W. Innys, at the West End of St. Paul's, 1743, page 128. Find it here.



Emerson does name the maxima $m$ , while not giving it much importance. Emerson also does not ignore $m$ where necessary. Turner (who already knew what Solution was eventually wanted) unnecessarily gives importance to the maxima , while contradictorily ignoring it ! Turner just wants to get to the Solution to match the "general rule" , no matter what mistakes are made and canceled along the way.
